# Get value from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a variable named $all and when I do print_r($all) it prints out this:

```
Array ( [2016] => Array ( [target] => 150 [tv1] => 32 [radio1] => 8 [tv2] => 19 [radio2] => 50 [tv3] => 30 [radio3] => 11 [tv4] => 10 [radio4] => 33 [total_actual] => 193 [variance] => 43 [variance_reason] => Reason one ) [2017] => Array ( [target] => 120 [tv1] => 34 [radio1] => 21 [tv2] => 31 [radio2] => 44 [tv3] => 12 [radio3] => 25 [tv4] => 20 [radio4] => 19 [total_actual] => 206 [variance] => 86 [variance_reason] => ) )
```

How can I pull out only `2016` and `2017` (keys of array)? Thank you!

Comment: `array_keys($arr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `array_keys()`:-

```
array_keys($all);
```

Example:- https://eval.in/728660

Answer (score 1):

```
print($all['2016']);
```

and

```
print($all['2017']);
```